# MSDN Help as XML or JSON data instead of HTML page

Tags: c#, .net, msdn

I am trying to build a help tool for .NET BCL classes. Does Microsoft provide MSDN help pages as XML file or JSON or REST?

Comment: Have you tried the ScriptFree version? Might that be good enough?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you can access it here http://services.msdn.microsoft.com/ContentServices/ContentService.asmx as XML